# How can I achieve below effect through material design

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Kindly advise how can I achieve below material design effect in Android. Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green button is a widget called [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button) (FAB).

Comment: Green Bar is Linear Layout. Right?. Never thought from this perspective. I have few more basic doubt pertaining to Image upload download progress visibility. Can I open tickets and tag for answer

Comment: I cannot look the the green bar well (because you painted it to hide the text) but it looks like a kind of [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar).